# Generate proper LaTeX table using tabulate Python package

Tags: python, latex

I'm using the [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate/) Python package to generate a properly LaTeX formatted table.

Here's a MWE:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [[r"${:.1f}\pm{:.1f}$".format(2.3564, 0.5487)],
         [r"${:.1f}\pm{:.1f}$".format(45.1236, 8.00021)]
         ]

print tabulate(table, tablefmt="latex")
```

What I get with this example is:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
 \$2.4\textbackslash{}pm0.5\$  \\
 \$45.1\textbackslash{}pm8.0\$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

when the proper formatting would be:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
 $2.4\pm0.5$  \\
 $45.1\pm8.0$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I.e.: the package is inserting backlashes before the `$` symbols, and replacing the backlash in `\pm` with `\textbackslash{}`.

Is it possible to generate the correct formatted table?

Answer (score 10):

Change the `tablefmt` so that it is equal to `latex_raw`. From the documentation:

> `latex_raw` behaves like `latex` but does not escape LaTeX commands
>   and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
tabulate.LATEX_ESCAPE_RULES = {}
```

worked for me

```
>>> tabulate.LATEX_ESCAPE_RULES = {}
>>> print(tabulate.tabulate([[r'\alpha']], tablefmt='latex'))

\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
 \alpha \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This results in an error in the `tabulate.tabulate()` line: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tabulate'`

Comment: @Gabriel, the above answer likely uses `import tabulate` rather than `from tabulate import tabulate`.