# Is there a way in Python 3.7 to turn a string equation into a formulated equation like Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: python, output, formula, equation, python-3.7

I'm trying to change an input of, say, `"3^2+4^2=5^2"` into an equation with the little 2's above the main numbers. What would be the way I'd convert that 1st string into the formula shown in the image?

I've tried searching for some surface-level solutions but haven't found any so far.

The only code I have is code that will print a string such as: [`"1 / x"`](https://www5a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP351bh01f4fga5e82h2000026gc51504a113dgd?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=21), [`"x ** x"`](https://www5a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP6539236281c9i3f5h5100000649ff873hi73a9ge?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54) or [`"x ** 2"`](https://www5a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP71231d7e2h1f965824dg000038d6i7520ef378i5?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=40) as is but I want to make some code that would output equations like the links they're attached to.

```
lst = [
"equal",
"squared",
"denominator",
"cubed",
"^x"]

lstDict = ({
"equal":"x",
"squared":"x ** 2",
"denominator":"1 / x",
"cubed":"x ** 3",
"^x":"x ** x"})

print(lstDict[lst[i]].replace("**", "^"))
```

where `i` is a count used to limit the length of a `while` loop and to count up the dictionary of equations.

Comment: What do you mean by "equation"? You mean a *formatted string*, or something like what you could get form `sympy`, the computer algebra system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SymPy package can do this for you: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. I'm trying to use MatPlotLib to output a bunch of data and one of the columns is equations. Would you have any suggestions for how to print the equation form that SymPy allows for in a table as MatPlotLib makes?

Comment: SymPy can output latex: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#latex and matplotlib can display latex https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/usetex_demo.html. You might even get away with using only the matplotlib's capability of rendering latex.

Comment: I'm sorry but for whatever reason, I said MatPlotLib and meant to instead say Tabulate. I'm attempting to display the equation in a column on a tab using Tabulate and instead of getting the proper equation which SymPy gives I just get a string like "m ** 2".

Comment: Tabulate can also handle latex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418787/generate-proper-latex-table-using-tabulate-python-package.